# Directive in AngularJS is firing $watch callback functions on load

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive:

```
  leafletDirective = angular.module("leaflet-directive", [])
  leafletDirective.directive "leaflet", ($http, $log)  ->
    restrict: "E"
    replace: true
    transclude: true
    template: "<div id=\"map\"></div>"
    scope:
      origin: "=origin"
      points: "=points"
      shape: "=shape"
      clearmarkers: "=clearmarkers"
      markers: "=markers"
    link: (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) ->

      scope.origin = [40.094882122321145, -3.8232421874999996]
      scope.points = []
      scope.shape = []
      #create a CloudMade tile layer and add it to the map
      @map = L.map(attrs.id,
                  center: scope.origin
                  zoom: 5
      )
      L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/57cbb6ca8cac418dbb1a402586df4528/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                maxZoom: 18
      ).addTo @map


      #add markers dynamically
      updateMarkers = (pts) =>
        console.log "loading markers"
        scope.markers = []
        for p of pts
          lat = pts[p].lat
          lng = pts[p].lng
          latLng = new L.LatLng(lat,lng)
          marker = new L.marker(latLng).addTo(@map)
          scope.markers.push(marker)
        return scope.markers

      #/// Add Polygon
      updateShape = (points) ->
        console.log "loading shape"

      #///Watch for point changes///##
      scope.$watch attrs.points,( (value) ->
        updateMarkers value
      ), true


      #//Watch For Shape Changes///###
      scope.$watch attrs.shape,( (value) ->
        updateShape value
      ), true
```

I am finding that on page load my watchers

```
      #///Watch for point changes///##
      scope.$watch attrs.points,( (value) ->
        updateMarkers value
      ), true


      #//Watch For Shape Changes///###
      scope.$watch attrs.shape,( (value) ->
        updateShape value
      ), true
```

Are firing on load... and I am seeing those messages from the functions they load. This is off because neither of the attrs have changed.

This is how I load Angular:

```
app = angular.module("WhereToMeet", ["leaflet-directive"])

@MapCtrl = ($scope) ->

  $scope.clicked = ->
    $scope.points.push(
      {lat: 1, lng: 2}, {lat: 40.094882122321145, lng: -3.8232421874999996}
    )


  $scope.clear = ->
    $scope.clearmarkers($scope.markers)

  $scope.makeShape = ->
    $scope.shape = []
    $scope.shape = ["1"]
```

I cant figure out why it loads on page load. The data does not change. Unless - it simply being created will do that - which I need to get around.

Answer (score 8):

> After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener fn is called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher. In rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when the result of watchExpression didn't change. To detect this scenario within the listener fn, you can compare the newVal and oldVal. If these two values are identical (===) then the listener was called due to initialization. -- [Scope#$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

Answer (score 5):

I have simplified my $watch statements to:

```
scope.$watch('someVar', function(newVal) {
  if (newVal) {
    // now, it's time to do something with scope.someVar
  }
});
```

Comment: I usually use this one, too. However, I have found that it can cause problems in things like search/filter boxes if the user erases everything (presumably to remove the filtering). In that case, since `someVar` will now be a blank string, and "falsey", no action will occur. Not always a problem, but something to note.